# Compiling as files with mxmlc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mxmlc

I try to compile my as files with mxmlc and ant.

Here is my compile code snipet:

```
<target name="compile">
    <exec executable="${flex.home}/${mxmlc}" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="-compiler.include-libraries='./libs'"/>
        <arg line="-compiler.optimize=true"/>
        <arg line="-debug=false"/>
        <arg line="-keep-generated-actionscript=false"/>
        <arg line="-default-frame-rate=60"/>
        <arg line="-default-size 800 600"/>
        <arg line="-source-path='./src'"/>
        <arg line="'./src/main.as'"/>
        <arg line="-o='./bin/main.swf'"/>
        <arg line="-use-network=true"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

My problem is that resulting swf is too big. It includes files that exists in `./src` but are not used in project. Moreover, it includes `mx.*` and other packages.

What would be proper mxmlc config?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `library-path`, not `include-libraries` directive.